# Lagrange Remainder Theorem - Abbot's Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

Currently going through Stephen Abbot's Understanding Analysis and I've just gotten to the proof of Lagrange's Remainder Theorem, which states that if we have $x\ne 0$ then there is some $|c|<|x|$ such that:
$$ E_N (x) = f (x) − S_N (x) = \frac{f^{(N+1)}(c)}{(N+1)!}x^{N+1}$$
He then proceeds to not do much else with taylor remainders.

From my perspective, this theorem is completely useless as a conclusion. It tells us how the error behaves at one specific point (and we don't even know where that is), and cannot even bound it in an $\epsilon$-neighborhood, when what we really want to do is upper bound $E_N(x)$ in some reasonably sized interval.

Are there any proofs of the error bounds of Taylor Series on intervals that are accessible at this stage of the book?

Comment: For a lot of specific functions $f$ you can easily get the type of bound you want. For example, $f$ could be $\sin$ or $\cos$ or the exponential function. The denominator $(N+1)!$ in the remainder term grows very quickly. This formula for the remainder is excellent.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. I would like to, for example, bound the absolute error of the taylor series of $\sin(x)$ by some $\epsilon$ within the interval $[-1,1]$ and find the least value of $N$ for which this is guaranteed. This bound gets me an $N$ that is only guaranteed to work for the given $\epsilon$ at some point $c$, and even more unhelpfully, doesn't even tell me what that $c$ is. Is it possible to go from the latter to the former somehow?

Comment: If $f(x) = \sin(x)$, then $| f^{(N+1)}(c) | \leq 1$ for all $c$ and for all positive integers $N$. So for any $ x \in [-1, 1]$ the absolute error in Taylor’s approximation is at most $1/(N+1)!$.

Comment: For another example, if $f(x) = e^x$ then $| f^{(N+1)}(c) | = e^c$ for all $c$. If we restrict our attention to the interval $[-M, M]$ then we know that $e^c \leq e^M$. So the error in Taylor’s approximation is bounded by $\frac{ e^M M^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}$  which approaches $0$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah... I was misreading the theorem as saying $E_N(c)=\dots$ as opposed to $E_N(x)=\dots$. Having read it correctly, this makes a lot more sense. Thanks for your patience!